# How would I make this curl request in C#?

Tags: c#, curl

This the the curl request I need to make in C#:

```
curl -X PURGE http://www.example.com/image.jpg
```

It is the PURGE part that is throwing me off, I was going to do this in RestSharp but WebClient or whatever will work just fine as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find `HttpClient` to be a convenient way to send requests these days. The key is to recognize that [you can create a custom HttpMethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19596386/using-a-custom-value-for-httpmethod) by passing a string to its constructor.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(
    new HttpMethod("PURGE"), 
    new Uri("http://www.example.com/image.jpg")))
using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
{
    // work with response
}
```